# Add @property method to a class

Tags: python, oop, syntactic-sugar

One can add a method to a python class with:

```
class foo(object):
    pass

def donothing(self):
    pass

foo.y = donothing
```

Then one would call the method with:

```
f = foo()
f.y()
```

Is there a way to add `@property` to the `def` as well, so to call it with

```
f.y
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the @property before the method definition

```
... class Foo(object):
...    pass
...
>>> @property
... def bar(self):
...     print("bar is called")
... 
>>> Foo.bar = bar
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar
bar is called
```

Answer (score 4):

Assign the return value of the [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
>>> class foo(object):
...     pass
...
>>> def donothing(self):
...     print('donothing is called')
...
>>> foo.y = property(donothing)  # <----
>>> f = foo()
>>> f.y
donothing is called
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, It can be specified as :

```
class foo(object):
    def __int__(self):
        self._y = None

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._y = value



>>>>x = foo()
>>>>x.y = str
>>>>print type(x.y(12.345)), x.y(12.345)
<type 'str'> 12.345
```

Here, I'm just saying that the attribute **y** (yes an attribute and not a method !), is set to **value**. Since everything is an object in Python, I can perfectly assign a function to a variable. The method associated with the attribute **y** (there as a property), returns the value of the attribute, which turns to be a function (**str** in this case). The returned value is used as a callable, which is exactly what we expected. Though, accessing the attribute **y** returns as a callable, effectively calling **str()**

I can assign any fucntion to **y** like this :

```
def double(x):
    return 2 * x

...

>>>>x.y = double
>>>>print x.y(33)
66
```

And so on...

Comment: OP did not say `donothing` was a method of `foo`.